# Error when adding react-native-web to an existing react-native app

Tags: react-native, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader, react-native-web

I created a react-native app, by doing `react-native init ReactNativeWeb`.

Then, I followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/blob/master/docs/guides/multi-platform-apps.md), to add react-native-web to it.

I also added an `index.web.js` file under the root folder of my app. Here's what the file looks like:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

class ReactNativeWeb extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native!</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit index.web.js
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>Press Cmd+R to reload</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF"
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: "center",
    margin: 10
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: "center",
    color: "#333333",
    marginBottom: 5
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent("ReactNativeWeb", () => ReactNativeWeb);
AppRegistry.runApplication("ReactNativeWeb", {
  rootTag: document.getElementById("react-app")
});
```

Here's my `webpack.config.js` file:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

const appDirectory = path.resolve(__dirname, "../");

// This is needed for webpack to compile JavaScript.
// Many OSS React Native packages are not compiled to ES5 before being
// published. If you depend on uncompiled packages they may cause webpack build
// errors. To fix this webpack can be configured to compile to the necessary
// `node_module`.
const babelLoaderConfiguration = {
  test: /\.js$/,
  // Add every directory that needs to be compiled by Babel during the build.
  include: [
    path.resolve(appDirectory, "index.web.js"),
    path.resolve(appDirectory, "src"),
    path.resolve(appDirectory, "node_modules/react-native-uncompiled")
  ],
  use: {
    loader: "babel-loader",
    options: {
      cacheDirectory: true,
      // The 'react-native' preset is recommended to match React Native's packager
      presets: ["react-native"],
      // Re-write paths to import only the modules needed by the app
      plugins: ["react-native-web"]
    }
  }
};

// This is needed for webpack to import static images in JavaScript files.
const imageLoaderConfiguration = {
  test: /\.(gif|jpe?g|png|svg)$/,
  use: {
    loader: "url-loader",
    options: {
      name: "[name].[ext]"
    }
  }
};

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    // load any web API polyfills
    // path.resolve(appDirectory, 'polyfills-web.js'),
    // your web-specific entry file
    path.resolve(appDirectory, "index.web.js")
  ],

  // configures where the build ends up
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.web.js",
    path: path.resolve(appDirectory, "dist")
  },

  // ...the rest of your config

  module: {
    rules: [babelLoaderConfiguration, imageLoaderConfiguration]
  },

  resolve: {
    // This will only alias the exact import "react-native"
    alias: {
      "react-native$": "react-native-web"
    },
    // If you're working on a multi-platform React Native app, web-specific
    // module implementations should be written in files using the extension
    // `.web.js`.
    extensions: [".web.js", ".js"]
  }
};
```

And, here's what I have in the `.bablerc` file:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

But, when I try to run this with the following command, I get the error below.

```
./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server -d --config ./web/webpack.con
```

Error:

> ERROR in ./index.web.js
>   Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'bindings' of null
>       at Scope.moveBindingTo (/Users/aliyar/ReactNativeWeb/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/scope/index.js:867:13)
>       at BlockScoping.updateScopeInfo (/Users/aliyar/ReactNativeWeb/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping/lib/index.js:364:17)
>       at BlockScoping.run (/Users/aliyar/ReactNativeWeb/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping/lib/index.js:330:12)
>       at PluginPass.BlockStatementSwitchStatementProgram (/Users/aliyar/ReactNativeWeb/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping/lib/index.js:70:24)
>       at newFn (/Users/aliyar/ReactNativeWeb/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/visitors.js:193:21)
>       at NodePath._call (/Users/aliyar/ReactNativeWeb/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:53:20)
>       at NodePath.call (/Users/aliyar/ReactNativeWeb/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:40:17)
>       at NodePath.visit (/Users/aliyar/ReactNativeWeb/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:88:12)
>       at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/Users/aliyar/ReactNativeWeb/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:118:16)
>       at TraversalContext.visitSingle (/Users/aliyar/ReactNativeWeb/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:90:19)
>    @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./index.web.js main[2]

Any idea why I get the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to fix your problem by upgrading the `babel-preset-react-native` to version 5.0.2. Everything else should be identical to your setup.

Here is my complete `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "ReactNativeWeb02",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "build": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server -d --config ./web/webpack.config.js --inline --hot --colors"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-native": "0.58.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.10.0-alpha.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-react-native-web": "^0.9.13",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^5.0.2",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.51.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "webpack": "^4.29.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: @Hi Цветан Иванов, I have followed the same instructions, build got compiled successfully, with the **yarn build** command. But app did not started in the browser, I have even opened the **http://localhost:8080/** url in browser. Could you please help me here.

Comment: @ataravati is this the same case for you?

Comment: @srikanth No, as far as I remember. I’m not working on that app anymore.